# Why Could not find artifacts for contract from any sources

Tags: ethereum, truffle, ganache

I am using windows 10 with truffle and ganache-cli. I have 2 contracts file to be deployed contain interfaces of other contracts defined within the contract:

Contracts:

**ERC721Mintable.sol**

- Ownable
- Pausable is Ownable
- ERC165
- ERC721 is Pausable, ERC165
- ERC721Enumerable is ERC165, ERC721
- ERC721MetaData is ERC721Enumerable, usingOraclize
- CraveuERC721Token is ERC721MetaData

**Verifier.sol**

**SolnSquareVerifier.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import "./ERC721Mintable.sol";
import "./Verifier.sol";

contract SolnSqaureVerifier is CraveuERC721Token {

    SquareVerifier squareVerifier;

    constructor(address verifierAddress) public {
        squareVerifier = SquareVerifier(verifierAddress);
    }
```

Here's my deploy_contracts.js:

```
const SquareVerifier = artifacts.require("Verifier");
const SolnSquareVerifier = artifacts.require("SolnSquareVerifier");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SquareVerifier).then( () => {
    return deployer.deploy(SolnSquareVerifier, SquareVerifier.address);
  });
};
```

I am using truffle version 5.0.18

> Error Produced: Error: Error: Could not find artifacts for
>   SolnSquareVerifier from any sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your contract name `SolnSqaureVerifier`, it should be `SolnSquareVerifier`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the filename of your smart contract is consistent and in capital letters, for example

- **`HealthContract.sol`,** don't name it like `healtcontract.sol` or `health_contract.sol`.
- Inside the smart contract, maintain the same naming convention, specifying it as `contract HealthContract`.

## Example

```
  solidity
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
  
  contract HealthContract {
      // Smart contract logic
  }
```

## Followed By

```
  var HealthRecord = artifacts.require('HealthContract');

  module.exports = function (deployer) {
      deployer.deploy(HealthRecord)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the .sol file in contract folder to any name that you want.
Then `truffle migrate` again.